# How to use event like (onSelect) instead of (change)

Tags: angular, multi-select

> because for (change) event to trigger , We  need to change the selected data in UI. Can we use EventEmitter for this. I want one event which gets triggered when we select one or more elements. Thanks

`<select multiple (change)="setSelected($event.target)">
    <option *ngFor="#item of myOptions" [value]="item.value">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>`

```
export class myClass { 
...
myOptions: [];
...
setSelected(selectElement) {
    for (var i = 0; i < selectElement.options.length; i++) {
        var optionElement = selectElement.options[i];
        var optionModel = this.myOptions[i];

        if (optionElement.selected == true) { optionModel.selected = true; }
        else { optionModel.selected = false; }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you can use ngmodel and ngmodelchange on the select element to trigger an event when the value changes

Comment: Your going from a child class to a parent right?  I <select-multiple> is in a component serving as a container?

Answer (score 1):

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="setSelected($event)">
setSelected(newVal) {
    this.selectedItem = newVal //If changing the model is required
    // ... do other stuff here ...
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Not Really , I have a case where elements in multi select are fixed or coming from some place , and I  have to pick one or many and have to use this somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you can achieve this with `ngModel`

```
<select multiple [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions" (change)="getSelected()">
    <option *ngFor="let item of myOptions" [value]="item.value">
        {{item.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

`selectedOptions` is an array of the selected option values in your dropdown. You can use the `change` event or the `ngModelChange` event to detect when 1 or multiple options are selected.

Here is a stackblitz demonstrating this (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bvchcj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)